# TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a weird looking dataframe that I need to wrangle. It looks something like this:

```
   Unnamed: 0       REFERENCE_CODE  ... Unnamed: 12  Unnamed: 13
0          Q2        country_satis  ...         NaN          NaN
1         NaN                    1  ...         NaN          NaN
2         NaN                    2  ...         NaN          NaN
3         NaN                    8  ...         NaN          NaN
4         NaN                    9  ...         NaN          NaN
5         NaN                  NaN  ...         NaN          NaN
6          Q3             econ_sit  ...         NaN          NaN
5         NaN                  NaN  ...         NaN          NaN
7         NaN                    1  ...         NaN          NaN
8         NaN                    2  ...         NaN          NaN
9         NaN                    3  ...         NaN             
10        NaN                    4  ...         NaN          NaN
11        NaN                    8  ...         NaN          NaN
12        NaN                    9  ...         NaN          NaN
13        NaN                  NaN  ...         NaN          NaN
14         Q4  children_betteroff2  ...         NaN  Не четете! 
15        NaN                    1  ...         NaN          NaN
16        NaN                    2  ...         NaN          NaN
15        NaN                  NaN  ...         NaN          NaN
18        NaN                    8  ...         NaN          NaN
19        NaN                    9  ...         NaN          NaN
20        NaN                  NaN  ...         NaN          NaN
21         Q5  satisfied_democracy  ...         NaN          NaN
22        NaN                    1  ...         NaN          NaN
23        NaN                    2  ...         NaN          NaN
24        NaN                    3  ...         NaN          NaN
```

(I made some edits to the original here in order to reflect what may appear in this very long dataframe). My goal here is to produce a unique ID for each of the values (ex. 1,2,8,9) associated to a question (ex. country_statis). I am attempting to concatenate  country_satis to 1, so that all of my "blocks" have

```
0          Q2        country_satis  ...         NaN          NaN
1         NaN     country_statis_1  ...         NaN          NaN
2         NaN     country_statis_2  ...         NaN          NaN
3         NaN     country_statis_8  ...         NaN          NaN
4         NaN     country_statis_9  ...         NaN          NaN
5         NaN                  NaN  ...         NaN          NaN
```

Here is my attempt:

```
df.REFERENCE_CODE = df.REFERENCE_CODE.fillna('')

df.REFERENCE_CODE.str.isnumeric().dtype # returns object

headers = (df.REFERENCE_CODE != '') & ~df.REFERENCE_CODE.str.isnumeric()

res = df.groupby(headers.cumsum())['REFERENCE_CODE'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] + '_' + x)

df.REFERENCE_CODE.update(res[df.REFERENCE_CODE.str.isnumeric()])
```

My goal here is also to keep the integrity and structure of the data, because eventually, ideally, I'd like to perform a clean merge of 2 data sources. I should probably do this in SQL lol.

Error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Projects/trend_env/src/script4.py", line 10, in <module>
    df.REFERENCE_CODE = df.REFERENCE_CODE.fillna('')
  File "/Users/xx/Projects/trend_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'REFERENCE_CODE'
```

EDIT:

I'm so sorry, I posted the wrong script error.. here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Projects/trend_env/src/script4.py", line 16, in <module>
    headers = (df.REFERENCE_CODE != '') & ~df.REFERENCE_CODE.str.isnumeric()
  File "/Users/xxx/Projects/trend_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1466, in __invert__
Index(['Question number', 'REFERENCE_CODE', 'Filter', 'English stem',
       'Translator note', 'Philippines - Bicolano', 'Philippines - Cebuano',
       'Philippines - Ilonggo', 'Philippines Ilokano', 'Philippines - Tagalog',
       'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 11', 'Unnamed: 12', 'Unnamed: 13'],
      dtype='object')
    arr = operator.inv(com.values_from_object(self))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

---

EDIT2:

As per Andy Hayden -- do you mind helping me solve this logic.. I have the code working just fine.  I have a case where the df looks like this:

```
25                     partyfav_batt                   NaN
26            partyfav_bulgaria_GERB                   NaN
27             partyfav_bulgaria_BSP                   NaN
28             partyfav_bulgaria_DPS                   NaN
29                                                     NaN
30           partyfav_bulgaria_DPS_1                   NaN
31           partyfav_bulgaria_DPS_2                   NaN
32           partyfav_bulgaria_DPS_3                   NaN
33           partyfav_bulgaria_DPS_4                   NaN
34           partyfav_bulgaria_DPS_8                   NaN
35           partyfav_bulgaria_DPS_9                   NaN
36                                                     NaN
37                     partyfav_batt                   NaN
38               partyfav_canada_Lib                   NaN
39              partyfav_canada_Cons                   NaN
40               partyfav_canada_NDP                   NaN
41                                                     NaN
42             partyfav_canada_NDP_1                   NaN
43             partyfav_canada_NDP_2                   NaN
44             partyfav_canada_NDP_3                   NaN
45             partyfav_canada_NDP_4                   NaN
46             partyfav_canada_NDP_8                   NaN
47             partyfav_canada_NDP_9                   NaN
```

How can I get it, so that if it sees a chunk...

```
37                     partyfav_batt                   NaN
38               partyfav_canada_Lib                   NaN
39              partyfav_canada_Cons                   NaN
40               partyfav_canada_NDP                   NaN
```

It turns into something like this (I have condensed it):

```
39              partyfav_canada_Cons                   NaN
40               partyfav_canada_NDP                   NaN
41                                                     NaN
42            partyfav_canada_Cons_1                   NaN
43            partyfav_canada_Cons_2                   NaN
44            partyfav_canada_Cons_3                   NaN
45            partyfav_canada_Cons_4                   NaN    
42             partyfav_canada_NDP_1                   NaN
43             partyfav_canada_NDP_2                   NaN
44             partyfav_canada_NDP_3                   NaN
45             partyfav_canada_NDP_4                   NaN
```

Comment: Their might be space in front of your column name, check df.columns

Comment: Nope, returned 'REFERENCE_CODE'

Comment: The example above worked for me...

Comment: Edits above, I'm sorry... what do you mean it worked? Can you show me output?

Comment: @sgerbhctim Your attempt ran as expected without error when I copied your example df above and read from the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `fillna` first:

```
~df.REFERENCE_CODE.fillna('').str.isnumeric()
```

---

Example:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['1', np.nan, 'c'])

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0      1
1    NaN
2      c
dtype: object

In [13]: s.str.isnumeric()
Out[13]:
0     True
1      NaN
2    False
dtype: object

In [14]: ~s.str.isnumeric()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2e51f8bd1622> in <module>()
----> 1 ~s.str.isnumeric()

~/.miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __invert__(self)
   1141     def __invert__(self):
   1142         try:
-> 1143             arr = operator.inv(com._values_from_object(self))
   1144             return self.__array_wrap__(arr)
   1145         except Exception:

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

In [15]: ~s.fillna('').str.isnumeric()
Out[15]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you so much.  I have made some edits above, if you don't mind helping me solve this logic, it would be of massive help.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @sgerbhctim please create a new question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596384/how-to-concatenate-by-batch-chunk-of-strings-set

Comment: Thank you so much @Andy Hayden

Comment: @sgerbhctim Thanks will look at later (or maybe someone will have already answered).

Comment: @AndyHayden how do you copy cells input and output to StackOverflow?