# TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float' while groupby and apply a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I get a TypeError while using groupby and a function to remove outliers:

```
def is_outlier(s):
    lower_limit = s.median() - (s.std() * 3)
    upper_limit = s.median() + (s.std() * 3)
    return ~s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)
df1 = df[~df.groupby('objectName')['price'].apply(is_outlier)]

print(df1)
```

I have filtered NaN rows in `price` column with: `df = df[np.isfinite(df['price'])]`, what I should do to make it return correctly? Thanks for helps at advance.

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1143, in __invert__
    arr = operator.inv(com._values_from_object(self))

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

This is what I get with `df['price'].describe()`, seems quite normal.

```
count    10755.000000
mean         7.135314
std          3.844756
min          1.000000
25%          4.700000
50%          6.000000
75%          8.500000
max         49.000000
```

References related:

[TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297740/typeerror-bad-operand-type-for-unary-float)

[TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585333/typeerror-bad-operand-type-for-unary-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion `std` return `NaN`s for groups with length `1`, so use `fillna`:

```
def is_outlier(s):
    lower_limit = s.median() - (s.std() * 3)
    upper_limit = s.median() + (s.std() * 3)
    return s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)

df1 = df[~df.groupby('objectName')['price'].apply(is_outlier).fillna(True)]
```